# Is experience abroad important for your career?

Tags: geochemistry

I'm just finishing my Bachelor's degree in Geochemistry at a German university and will soon start my Master's degree, but I've been wondering for a few weeks whether a stay abroad (1 semester or even 1 year) is important and when it's best to do it. In other words, should I do it during my Master's degree or during my dissertation?

What are your experiences, or has an experience abroad been important for your academic career?

I am aware that this question can be closed because of Option Based/OFF TOPIC. But I also didn't want to ask this question on Earth Science Meta, because this question doesn't fit there either!

Comment: There is a good fit for this kind of questions: [Academia SE](https://academia.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a perspective from an oceanographer, in the hiring process, academic institutions definitely take into account your time abroad and collaborations you've cultivated along the way. If you're intending on doing a PhD, I would suggest that this would be the best time for you to pursue your studies/research abroad.